# How to use Visual Studio Team Services as a NuGet feed in LINQPad

Tags: nuget, linqpad, azure-artifacts

I am using LINQPad 5 and VSTS (visual studio team services)
I have a NuGet feed (v3) in VSTS and I would like to use packages from there(private) in LINQPad

I have tried using the personal access token from VSTS as the NuGet password in LINQPad
I have tried putting the VSTS credential provider for nuget in *AppData\Local\NuGet\CredentialProviders*
I have tried putting the VSTS credential provider for nuget in *AppData\Local\LINQPad\NuGet\CredentialProviders*
I have tried using my VSTS username and password as the nuget credentials

How is this done? Is there a bug in LINQPad? Is this not supported yet?

Comment: LINQPad supports only standard NuGet authentication right now, so a personal access token should be the solution. I don't have a VSTS feed to test, so I cannot say why this doesn't work. Can you test your personal access token in another way, say from the NuGet command-line from a machine without the NuGet VSTS Credential Provider installed?

Comment: I got it to work using the token as the username and a blank password. My mistake was using the token as a password

Comment: Actually maybe it's not working as the username, it might be getting cached from the manual nuget.exe run

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We managed to get it to work by using the v2 nuget API:

```
/nuget/v2
```

instead of:

```
/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Just put the personal access token in the password text box on LINQPad Package Sources dialog box.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, or at least only partially works. I have a feed with > 300 packages, but the v2 index only returns a single package. If I change feeds and change back, it then throws a TF400813 "Resource not available for anonymous access"

Comment: Did not work for me neither. "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

Comment: Here is what works: Generate Personal Access Token (googlable) then you can stick in both username and password fields in the LinqPad settings.

Answer (score 1):

My current way of getting it to work is as follows:

- use nuget v2 feed
   `https://<instance>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed>/nuget/v2`
- put the personal access token in the password text box

  - make sure the access token is still valid...
- **restart linqpad** when in doubt! It seems to cache some old credentials (e.g. expired PAT) sometimes
- try disabling other feeds so you only have one feed enabled
- this helps sometimes: under advanced, enable *use legacy search engine (v2)*

Comment: Restart helped me. Thank you!

Comment: v3 works. Be sure to add your email as username. And no need to b64 encode the PAT

Answer (score 0):

i'm using a v3 feed in linqpad v6 following the format `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXX/_packaging/FEED/nuget/v3/index.json`

the only way i got it to work was using the PAT (having Packaging Read access) as the username, empty password. @joe-albahari's instructions on the forums and such to use the PAT it in the password field did not work.