# Adding a package with pre-release dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, linqpad, azure-artifacts

Using LINQPad I've added a private feed to Visual Studio Team Services. However one of my packages requires a pre-release package: Quartz.Net in my case. I've ticked Include Prerelease but I think it's getting confused and trying to load the package from my private feed rather than NuGet.

[image: LINQ NuGet Package Manager]

I've tried to work around the issue by loading the package into the local package cache. LINQPad doesn't seem to consider this. Other than uploading these packages into my own private feed, what options do I have? I'm not going to alter my own packages to get around LINQPad's shortcomings.

Note: I've setup the VSTS feed according this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514300/how-to-use-visual-studio-team-services-as-a-nuget-feed-in-linqpad).

Here is what my NuGet feeds look like in LINQPad

[image: LINQ NuGet Feeds]

Comment: Is your package a [pre-release package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages)? The pre-release package with pre-release dependence works fine in Visual Studio. On the other hand, how do you add VSTS feed to LINQPad, it is empty in LINQ Nuget Manager after adding my VSTS feed with PAT.

Comment: My package is not release in itself. I see the contradiction there, and because it depends on pre-release packages. Adding VSTS feed to LINQPad; source: https://yourcompanyname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyNuGetFeed/nuget/v2 username: email, password: PAT

Comment: Is Nuget official feed still enabled after add VSTS feed?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes, both are enabled. I've revised my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the package to pre-release fixes this issue, and add the pre-release packages dependencies to my own feed.

Now LINQPad attempts to add the package. Mind you I now get another error;

> "There are no usable .NET assemblies in package
>   'MyPackage.Common(Prerelease)'

That's down to NET Standard & NET47 support.